# Whats app business api media template create

Tags: laravel, curl, whatsapi

I'm facing an error when creating a media template with sample image file. I'm following the developer facebook documentation: "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates/#message--media----interactive-templates" and the section is "Example Media Template Request".

I'm trying the following code.

My component code is :

```
[{"type":"header","format":"IMAGE","example":{"header_handle":["https://edailyshopping.com/images/download.jpg"]}},{"type":"body","text":"Wishing you all Ramadan Mubarak."}]
```

API URL: [https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/{whatsapp-business-account-ID}/message_template](https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/%7Bwhatsapp-business-account-ID%7D/message_template)

response is getting success.

**The problem is template is created but the sample media file is not uploaded. **

Can anyone any idea about it why the sample image is not uploaded?

Comment: It is just for sample image and whatsapp use it for verification purpose, if your template is created then what is the issue?

Comment: Yes but the image is not uploading. For the verification purpose there need to upload that image. If I create a template from facebook business panel then we need to upload a sample image and that uploaded image is attached in the preview. But while i'm adding the image image via API that image is not uploading.  This is the issue. I need to upload a sample image via API for a template. Facebook provide only a document that i shared, but the process is not working.

Comment: If your template successfully approved then you don't need that image, and it is not usefull for you anymore.. because you have to upload it everytime when you send message with this template.

Comment: A template doesn't approved without a sample image. I have tried with the content which has already approved.

This message form meta:
The message template ramadan_mubarak_one has been rejected because it contains media.
What you can do:
- You need to either change this format or add a sample.
- Learn more about formatting in our message template guidelines.
- To request a review or more details about this rejection, contact WhatsApp Support

Comment: I think it requires to upload image using resumable-api, as per 4th point in [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/business-management-api/message-templates#before-you-start)

Comment: Okay ill try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252546/discussion-between-md-sehirul-islam-rehi-and-turivishal).